# woocommerce убрать стоимость доставки в админке в карточке заказа

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Подскажите как можно убрать стоимость доставки в админке wordpress. (Нижнюю строку в таблице с иконкой машиной). Это стандартный функционал расчета доставки (предпоследняя строка это товар "Доставка" для передачи в МойСклад. )  [image: пример заданной строки в админке]

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_created', 'evs_woocommerce_checkout_order_created_action' );
function evs_woocommerce_checkout_order_created_action($order ){

$new_ship_price = 0;    
$item = new WC_Order_Item_Shipping();
$item->set_total( $new_ship_price );
$item->calculate_taxes($calculate_tax_for);
$order->add_item( $item );
$order->calculate_totals();
$order->save(); 

}
```